# Use Material design icons library in a FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, material-design

I am making an app that uses a `FloatingActionButton` with a '+' icon, and I am using the [Materian Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) library to add icons. Is there any way I can use a Material Design icon fro this library in my `FloatingActionButton`?

---

My `FloatingActionButton` code so far is

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"/>
```

I don't have much else because I can't get an icon into the FAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you need first add icon image to `drawable` folder, then set icon to your FAB button, like this:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
  android:layout_width="56dp"
  android:layout_height="56dp"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_icon"
  />
```